# Logstash aggregate filter skipping records

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logstash

I am migrating data from mysql to Elasticsearch via logstash. I am using aggregate filter plugin.. I have user, post and post media tables. The scenerio is , a user has many post and post has many media. I want to save object as follow.

```
{
"id": "82219",
"name": "test",
"db_id": 82219,
"user_id": "u-48201",
"box_user": {
    "id": 48201,
    "box_id": 82219,
    "username": "fasdfasf",
    "full_name": "fasdf fasd",
    "is_private": true
},
"status": "A",
"created_at": "2020-01-06T13:04:00Z",
"type": {
    "name": "box",
    "parent": "u-82219"
},
"box_posts": [{
    "box_id": 82219,
    "post_box_id": 328341,
    "text_content": "Mango Duck",
    "created_at": "2017-01-17T20:49:09.000Z",
    "created_location": {
        "lon": -0.09,
        "lat": 51.5
    },
    "score": 96,
    "user_id": 48201,
    "post_media": [{

            "bg_color": "#C9273E",
            "file": "compress_749uyiwl14932043481493204348.jpg",
            "file_base_name": "compress_749uyiwl14932043481493204348",

        },
        {

            "bg_color": "#C9273E",
            "file": "compress_749uyiwl14932043481493204348.jpg",
            "file_base_name": "compress_749uyiwl14932043481493204348",

        },
        {

            "bg_color": "#C9273E",
            "file": "compress_749uyiwl14932043481493204348.jpg",
            "file_base_name": "compress_749uyiwl14932043481493204348",

        }
    ],
    "post_type_id": 1,
    "location": {
        "fs_location_id": "ChIJ03GSCloDdkgRe_s-p2vyvQA",
        "thumbnail": "",
        "website": "https://www.the-shard.com/",
        "other_info": "",

    },
    "id": 2,
    "place": {
        "lon": 51.5045,
        "lat": -0.0865
    },
    "short_code": "7M"
}, {
    "box_id": 82219,
    "post_box_id": 328342,
    "text_content": ""
    "Exploring canals "
    "",
    "created_at": "2017-01-17T20:53:27.000Z",
    "created_location": {
        "lon": -0.66,
        "lat": 51.8
    },
    "score": 36,
    "user_id": 48201,
    "post_media": [{
        "file_width": 1440,
        "notification_file_width": 1146,
        "thumb_file_height": 135,
        "home_file_height": 860,
        "is_primary": true,
    }],
    "post_type_id": 1,
    "location": {
        "fs_location_id": "ChIJ33SmFitYdkgR3-ErzH_p6Bw",
        "thumbnail": "",
        "website": "",
        "other_info": "",
        "rating": 0.0,
    },
    "id": 3,
    "place": {
        "lon": 51.992,
        "lat": -0.66
    },
    "short_code": "bxvbvxc"
}, ],
"@timestamp": "2020-02-11T13:26:01.806Z",
"@version": "1"
```

}

I used following filter.

>

> aggregate {
>   task_id => "%{db_id}"
>   code => "
>             map['db_id'] = event.get('db_id')
>
> ```
>       map['box_posts'] ||= []
>       model = {
>           'box_id' => event.get('box_id'),
>           'score' => event.get('score'),
>           'post_box_id' => event.get('post_box_id'),
>           'user_id' => event.get('user_id'),
>           'text_content' => event.get('text_content'),
>           'created_at' => event.get('post_created'),
>           'id' => event.get('post_id'),
>           'post_type_id' => event.get('post_type_id'),
>           'short_code' => event.get('short_code'),
>           'created_location' => { 'lon' =>  event.get('lon') ,  'lat' => event.get('lat') },
>       }
>
>       model['post_media'] = { 
>
>           'id' =>  event.get('media_id'), 
>           'bg_color' =>  event.get('bg_color'), 
>           'file' =>  event.get('media_file'), 
>           'file_base_name' =>  event.get('file_base_name'), 
>           'file_type' =>  event.get('file_type'), 
>           'file_type_number' =>  event.get('file_type_number'), 
>           'file_width' =>  event.get('file_width'), 
>           'file_height' =>  event.get('file_height'), 
>           'is_primary' =>  event.get('is_primary') , 
>           'file_size' =>  event.get('file_size'), 
>           'medium_file_width' =>  event.get('medium_file_width'),
>           'medium_file_height' =>  event.get('medium_file_height'), 
>           'thumb_file_height' =>  event.get('thumb_file_height'), 
>           'thumb_file_width' =>  event.get('thumb_file_width'), 
>           'collage_file_height' =>  event.get('collage_file_height'), 
>           'collage_file_width' =>  event.get('collage_file_width'), 
>           'notification_file_width' =>  event.get('notification_file_width'), 
>           'notification_file_height' =>  event.get('notification_file_height'), 
>           'home_file_height' =>  event.get('home_file_height'), 
>           'home_file_width' =>  event.get('home_file_width'), 
>           'md5_filename' =>  event.get('md5_filename'), 
>           'bucket' =>  event.get('media_bucket'), 
>           'bg_color_collage' =>  event.get('bg_color_collage') 
>       }
>
>
>       if (event.get('location_id') != nil)
>
>           model['location'] = { 
>               'fs_location_id' =>  event.get('fs_location_id') ,  
>               'location_name' =>  event.get('location_name') ,  
>               'map_image' =>  event.get('map_image') ,  #bool 
>               'address_name' =>  event.get('address_name') ,  
>               'bg_image' =>  event.get('location_bg_image') ,  
>               'thumbnail' =>  event.get('thumbnail') ,  
>               'rating' =>  event.get('location_rating') ,  # float
>               'total_reviews' =>  event.get('total_reviews') ,  
>               'file' =>  event.get('file') ,  
>               'bucket' =>  event.get('location_bucket') ,  
>               'width' =>  event.get('location_width') != '' ? event.get('location_width') : 0,  
>               'height' =>  event.get('location_height') != '' ? event.get('location_height'): 0,  
>               'phone' =>  event.get('location_phone') ,  
>               'other_info' =>  event.get('other_info') ,  
>               'website' =>  event.get('website')   
>
>           }
>           model['place'] = { 
>               'lon' =>  event.get('location_latitude') ,  
>               'lat' => event.get('location_longitude')
>           }
>       end
>
>
>       if ( event.get('post_type_id') == 7 )
>
>               source_type = event.get('search_post_source_type')
>
>           model['post_attributes'] = {
>               'title' => event.get('search_post_title') ,
>               'thumbnail' => event.get('search_post_thumbnail') ,
>               'bg_image' => event.get('search_post_bg_image') ,
>               'source_type' => event.get('search_post_source_type') ,
>               'source_id' => event.get('search_post_source_id') ,
>               'source_link' => event.get('search_post_source_link') ,
>               'item_type' => event.get('search_post_item_type') ,
>               'item_type_number' => event.get('search_post_item_type_number') ,
>               'rating' =>  event.get('search_post_rating'), 
>
>           }
>
>           if( source_type !=  'google' && source_type !=  'web'  )
>
>               model['post_attributes'].merge! ( {
>
>
>                   'source_title' => event.get('post_search_attribute_title'),
>                   'owner' =>  event.get('post_search_attribute_owner'), 
>                   'caption' =>  event.get('post_search_attribute_caption'), 
>                   'description' =>  event.get('post_search_attribute_description'), 
>                   'source_rating'  =>  event.get('post_search_attribute_rating'), 
>                   'total_reviews' =>  event.get('post_search_attribute_total_reviews'), 
>                   'total_likes' =>  event.get('post_search_attribute_total_likes'), 
>                   'total_dislikes' =>  event.get('post_search_attribute_total_dislikes'), 
>                   'total_pages' =>  event.get('post_search_attribute_total_pages'), 
>                   'gallery' =>  event.get('post_search_attribute_gallery'), 
>                   'stars' =>  event.get('post_search_attribute_stars'), 
>                   'trailers' =>  event.get('post_search_attribute_trailers'), 
>                   'external_url' =>  event.get('post_search_attribute_external_url')
>               })
>           end 
>
>           if( source_type ==  'google' && event.get('gallery') !=  nil  ) 
>               model['post_attributes'].merge! ( { 
>                   'trailers' =>  event.get('gallery') 
>               })
>           end 
>
>       end 
>           map['box_posts'] <<  model      event.cancel()"     push_previous_map_as_event => true      timeout => 5 }
> ```

Comment: What is your error or wrong behavior? How many workers your pipeline have? You should be using only one worker for the `aggregate` filter to work correctly.

Comment: Yes i have used only one worker as follow 
sudo bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/test.conf  -w 1 --java-execution=false
But still not working. The thing is i am not getting any error.